# HTML table from multiple different MySQL tables with different data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-table

Can't seem to figure this one out. I want to get data from three different tables into one table in my page.

My tables

```
People
+----+------+--------+------+
| id | name | status | date |
+----+------+--------+------+

House
+----+---------+--------+------+
| id | address | status | date |
+----+---------+--------+------+

Alarms
+----+------+--------+------+
| id | type | status | date |
+----+------+--------+------+
```

I want to get all data from those three tables where status is 2. How can I do that and get them in one html table ordered by date.

If someone could point me to the right direction that would be awesome.

Comment: How your tables are connected?

Comment: in other mean , what is the relation between tables ?

Comment: Yeah, there is no relation between the tables. That's my problem. Just three unique tables that needs to go to same html table.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about joining unrelated tables in SQL (which is non-sense)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 SELECT p.id,
        p.name,
        p.status,
        p.date, 
        h.address,
        a.type
 FROM people p
 INNER JOIN House h ON p.id = h.id  //this i just guessed the relation you should make your relation here
 INNER JOIN Alarms a ON h.id = a.id //this i just guessed the relation you should make your relation here
 WHERE p.status =2
 ORDER BY p.date
```

IF your tables have no relation then try this

```
 select id,'type' as type,name,'adress' as adress,status,date  from people where status =2
 union
 select id,'type' as type,name,adress,status,date  from House where status =2
 union
 select id,type,name,'adress' as adress,status,date  from people where status =2
```

Comment: How do we know they are connected by ID.. The IDs could just be identifying the individual house alarm and people...

Comment: i just guessed while he didnt show the relation but i will note it.

Comment: Yeah, there is no relation between the tables. That's my problem. Just three unique tables that needs to go to same html table.

Comment: Idea is to get all rows from those tables with status=2 which means they are activated

Comment: Can I make 3 sql queries and somehow unite those results with PHP?

Comment: Nice! This one works perfect for me. Thank you so much!